# In a React/Flux app, where does a delayed action timeout belong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I wasn't sure whether this question belongs on programmers or SO, so forgive me if I chose unwisely.

This is my first React/Flux app, so I'm still learning the ropes.

I have an app with a text input component.  I don't want to propagate a change every time a user types a character into the input (for performance reasons).  So in the input's `onChange` handler, I set the component's state to have the new value, check to see if a timeout is already queued (if so, clear it), and then kick off a new 500ms timeout that calls the change-value action which updates the store.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Input } from 'react-bootstrap';

import TableStore from '../stores/table-store';
import TableActions from '../actions/table-actions';

export default class TableEditorDescription extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            description: TableStore.getLoadedTable().description
        };
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        let description = e.target.value; // new value of the input
        this.setState({
            description: description
        });

        if (this._timeout) {
            clearTimeout(this._timeout);
        }

        this._timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            TableActions.setLoadedTableDesc(description);
        }, 500);
    }

    render() {
        return <Input ref='desc'
                    {...this.props}
                    type='textarea'
                    placeholder='description'
                    value={this.state.description}
                    onChange={this.handleChange} />;
    }
}
```

However, my save button (a sibling component) is disabled if there are no pending changes to save, and lights up when changes have been made.  In my current code, since the action is delayed, the button doesn't enable until a half second after the user stops typing.  More concerning is that, since the action waits half a second to take effect, if the save button is already enabled and the user clicks it within that half second, the wrong value is saved--the value of the input before the user started typing.

So my next thought was to call two actions--the delayed one, and one that eventually results in a different event being emitted, something like `'queuedChange'`, with the only component listening to it being the button.  Then, when the button is clicked, either the save action will wait for the other action to occur, or the store kicks it off artificially and tells the input to clear its timeout or something.

Then I thought that the right place for this delay might be the store, and so the store would maintain the timeouts for each of the actions that should be delayed (knowing whether to do the delay or just make the change immediately based on an action parameter).

Does anyone whose done something similar have some hindsighted advice?

Comment: Honestly, React is really fast. I wouldn't worry so much about updating the store every time a key is pressed.

Comment: in fact, React's documentation pretty much explicitly covers this. The React team's spent way more time than is reasonable on making sure React is lightning fast, don't waste your own time on this. Propagate every change, and trust that React and the Virtual DOM deals with it efficiently. Especially if this is your first React app, you have *nothing* to base your opinion on other than metrics, so don't try to optimize before you have stats that show React is being slow. Just write proper React code and follow proper React methodologies.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use _.debounce (or a similar version from your favorite library).

Answer (score 0):

Per comments, I did away with this because React is fast.